# Remove image sources with same class reference when web scraping in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to write some code to extract some data from transfermarkt ([Link Here for the page I'm using](https://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/league-one/transfers/wettbewerb/GB3/plus/?saison_id=2018&s_w=&leihe=1&intern=0&intern=1)). I'm stuck trying to print the clubs. I've figured out that I need to access h2 and then the a class in order to just get the text. The HTML code is below

```
<div class="table-header" id="to-349"><a class="vereinprofil_tooltip" id="349" href="/fc-barnsley/transfers/verein/349/saison_id/2018"><img src="https://tmssl.akamaized.net/images/wappen/small/349.png?lm=1574162298" title="&nbsp;" alt="Barnsley FC" class="" /></a><h2><a class="vereinprofil_tooltip" id="349" href="/fc-barnsley/transfers/verein/349/saison_id/2018">Barnsley FC</a></h2></div>
```

so you can see if I just try find_all("a", "class": "vereinprofil_tooltip"}) it doesn't work properly as it also returns the image file which has no plain text? But if I can search for h2 first and then search find_all("a", "class": "vereinprofil_tooltip"}) within the returned h2 it would get me what I want. My code is below.

```
import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


    headers = {'User-Agent':
               'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36'}

    page = "https://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/league-one/transfers/wettbewerb/GB3/plus/?saison_id=2018&s_w=&leihe=1&intern=0&intern=1"
    pageTree = requests.get(page, headers=headers)
    pageSoup = BeautifulSoup(pageTree.content, 'html.parser')
    #Players = pageSoup.find_all("a", {"class": "spielprofil_tooltip"})
    Clubs = pageSoup.find_all("h2")
    Club = Clubs.find("a", {"class": "vereinprofil_tooltip"})
    print(Club)
```

I get the error in **getattr**
    raise AttributeError(
AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'find_all'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?

I know what the error means but I've been going round in circles trying to find a way of actually doing it properly and getting what I want. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36'}

page = "https://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/league-one/transfers/wettbewerb/GB3/
plus/?saison_id=2018&s_w=&leihe=1&intern=0&intern=1"

pageTree = requests.get(page, headers=headers)
pageSoup = BeautifulSoup(pageTree.content, 'html.parser')
#Players = pageSoup.find_all("a", {"class": "spielprofil_tooltip"})
Clubs = pageSoup.find_all("h2")
print(type(Clubs)) # this can be removed, but I left it to expose how I figured this out
for club in Clubs:
    print(club.text)
```

Basically:  `Clubs` is a list (technically, a ResultSet, but the behavior is very similar), you need to iterate it as such. `.text` gives just the text, other attributes could be retrieved as well.

Output looks like:

```
Transfer record 18/19
Barnsley FC
Burton Albion
Sunderland AFC
Shrewsbury Town
Scunthorpe United
Charlton Athletic
Plymouth Argyle
Portsmouth FC
Peterborough United
Southend United
Bradford City
Blackpool FC
Bristol Rovers
Fleetwood Town
Doncaster Rovers
Oxford United
Gillingham FC
AFC Wimbledon
Walsall FC
Rochdale AFC
Accrington Stanley
Luton Town
Wycombe Wanderers
Coventry City
Transfer record 18/19
```

There are, however, a bunch of blank lines (I.e., `.text` was '') that you should probably handle as well.

Comment: Thank you so much. I was going round in circles trying to figure out how to handle it last night.

Answer (score 0):

my guess is you might mean findAll instead of find_all

I tried this code below and it works

```
content = """<div class="table-header" id="to-349">
    <a class="vereinprofil_tooltip" id="349" href="/fc-barnsley/transfers/verein/349/saison_id/2018">
        <img src="https://tmssl.akamaized.net/images/wappen/small/349.png?lm=1574162298" title="&nbsp;" alt="Barnsley FC" class="" />
    </a>
    <h2>
        <a class="vereinprofil_tooltip" id="349" href="/fc-barnsley/transfers/verein/349/saison_id/2018">
            Barnsley FC
        </a>
    </h2>
</div>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser')
#get main_box   
main_box = soup.findAll('a', {'class': 'vereinprofil_tooltip'})

#print(main_box)
for main_text in main_box: # looping thru the list
    if main_text.text.strip(): # get the body text
        print(main_text.text.strip()) # print it
```

output is 
`Barnsley FC`

I'll edit this with a reference to the documentation about findAll. cant remember it on to pof my head

edit:
did a look at the documentation, turns out find_all = findAll..
https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all
now I feel dumb lol